# Ubuntu 18.04 using PHP version that is not installed as a module

Tags: php, ubuntu

Using the commmand php -v on a Ubuntu 18.04 server is displaying PHP version 8.1.14, but no PHP8.* module is installed.

I have tried running the command: sudo update-alternatives --config php which displays:

[Available PHP versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABZAf.png)

Disabling the PHP8.1 module will show me that the module is not installed:

[module not installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC66y.png)

While php -v is really showing me PHP8.1:

[PHP version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqcY5.png)

I have tried to purge the PHP 8 version with the following command:

sudo apt-get purge php8.*

It showed me 0 modules were marked for removal, just to be sure I also ran autoremove & autoclean commands.

When I display the PHP info, it also shows the 8.1 version:

[PHP info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPoTh.png)

I need to get the server back to version 7.4 to make some installations function properly, I have tried all options above but did not succeed. How can I downgrade to PHP Version 7.4?

Answer (score 0):

While I was installing the PHP Selector add-on for DirectAdmin, I noticed Zend modules were being installed for 7.4. Perhaps these were missing for the server to switch back to version 7.4. Problem solved!